# Swift Youtube Player Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I am using Swift-YouTube-Player library.Here is a [link](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) !

I am listing videos in tableview.My problem is memory problem. I know that I should clear all videoPlayer.clean() before loading selected videoPlayer.

**My question is how can i clear every instances of the player in my app is cleared before loading another video.**

***My Code like this :***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let jlist = self.searchedJoinAllAllowedInnoList , !jlist.isEmpty{

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JoinCell", for: indexPath) as! JoinCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.indexPath = indexPath
            //--
            cell.videoName.text = jlist[indexPath.row].shortDesc
            cell.EndDate.text = getDate(unixdate: jlist[indexPath.row].joinEnd!, timezone: "UTC")
            if let videoKey = jlist[indexPath.row].teaserVideo , !videoKey.isEmpty{
                print("video key:\(videoKey)")
                cell.thubnailImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/\(videoKey)/hqdefault.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "lcw"))
                let playerVars = ["controls": "1", "playsinline": "1", "autohide": "1", "showinfo": "1", "autoplay": "0", "fs": "1", "rel": "0", "loop": "0", "enablejsapi": "1", "modestbranding": "1"]
                cell.videoPlayer.playerVars = playerVars as YouTubePlayerView.YouTubePlayerParameters
                cell.videoPlayer.clear()
            }

            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.textLabel?.text = "nodataavaiable".localized()
            return cell
        }
    }
```

***And my custom Play Button delegate is :***

```
extension JoinViewController : JoinCellButtonsDelegate {


    func playButtonDelegate(at index: IndexPath) {
        if let jlist = self.searchedJoinAllAllowedInnoList , !jlist.isEmpty{
            if let videoKey = jlist[index.row].teaserVideo , !videoKey.isEmpty{
                let cell = joinTableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! JoinCell

                cell.videoPlayer.clear()
                cell.videoPlayer.loadVideoID(videoKey)
                    cell.videoPlayer.play()
                    self.delayWithSeconds(2, completion: {
                        cell.videoPlayer.play()
                        cell.thubnailView.isHidden = true
                    })

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest to *profile* the issue, thus you might be able to easily solve it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I can try to use a weak cell reference in the last closure.

```
delayWithSeconds(2, completion: { [weak cell] in
     cell?.videoPlayer.play()
     cell?.thubnailView.isHidden = true
})
```

and do not forget to remove the previous line: `cell.videoPlayer.play()`.

Comment: cell is a local variable, so it won't create a retain cycle, it's not needed to mark as weak